# Named parameters compilation fails with @CompileStatic - how to fix it?

Tags: groovy, compile-static

This piece of code works perfectly in dynamically typed Groovy

```
buildDirectory.traverse(type: FILES, nameFilter: ~/dependency-updates-report.xml/) {
    reports << it
}
```

but when adding `@CompileStatic` to the class it get an error, something along the line

```
'traverse' in 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods' cannot be applied to ...
```

Is the `Map` parameter the problem here?

**EDIT** buildDirectory is of type `java.io.File` and is injected.

Comment: could you show the full error message ? and how `buildDirectory` is declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of a static compilation like that one, you need to make an explicit cast to:

```
buildDirectory.traverse([type: FILES, nameFilter: ~/dependency-updates-report.xml/] as Map) {
    reports << it
}
```

The problem here is that `File.traverse()` method expects a map of type

```
Map<String, Object>
```

while the Groovy idiomatic map creation creates a map of type

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Serializable>
```

This `Serializable` is a problem here because it is not a subclass of the `java.lang.Object`.